# How can I get the SOA serial number from a file with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I store my SOA data for multiple domains in a single file that gets `$INCLUDE`d by zone files.  I've written a small sed script that is supposed to get the serial number, increment it, then re-save the SOA file.  It all works properly as long as the SOA file is in the proper format, with the entire record on one line, but it fails as soon as the record gets split into multiple lines.

For example, this works as input data:

```
@ IN SOA dnsserver. hostmaster.example.net. ( 2013112202 21600  900 691200 86400 )
```

But this does not:

```
@ IN SOA dnsserver. hostmaster.example.net. (
                            2013112202      ; Serial number
                            21600           ; Refresh every day, 86400 is 1 day
                            900             ; Retry refresh every 15 min
                            691200          ; Expire every 8 days
                            86400 )         ; Minimum TTL 1 day
```

I *like* comments, and I would like to spread things out.  But I need my script to be able to find the serial number so that I can increment it and rewrite the file.

The SED that works on the single line is this:

```
SOA=$(sed 's/.*@.*SOA[^0-9]*//;s/[^0-9].*//' $SOAfile)
```

But for multi-line ... I'm a bit lost.  I know I can join lines with `N`, but how do I know if I even *need* to?  Do I need to write separate sed scripts based on some other analysis I do of the original file?

Please help!  :-)

Comment: Must you use sed?  Or will other tools do?

Comment: I'm open to other tools, but I'm in FreeBSD, so I'd rather not use stuff that requires things to be installed that don't ship with the base OS.  That rules out perl, python, ruby, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use sed for this.  While you might be able to brute-force something, it would require a large amount of concentration to come up with it, and it would look like line noise, and so be almost unmaintainable afterwards.

What about this in awk?

The easiest way might be to split your records based on the `@` character, like so:

```
SOA=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS="@"} NR==2{print $6}' $SOAfile)
```

But that will break if you have comments containing `@` before the uncommented line, or if you have any comments between the `@` and the serial number.  You could make a pipe to avoid these issues...

```
SOA=$(sed 's/;.*//;/^@/p;1,/^@/d' $SOAfile | awk 'BEGIN{RS="@"} NR==2{print $6}')
```

It may seem redundant to remove comments *and* strip the top of the file, but there could be other lines like `#include` which (however unlikely) could contain your record separator.

Or you could do something like this in pure awk:

```
SOA=$(awk -v field=6 '/^@/ { if($2=="IN"){field++} for(i=1;i<field;i++){if(i==NF){field=field-NF;getline;i=1}} print $field}' $SOAfile)
```

Or, broken out for easier reading:

```
awk -v field=6 '
  /^@/ {
    if ($2=="IN") {field++;}
    for (i=1;i<field;i++) {
      if(i==NF) {field=field-NF;getline;i=1;}
    }
    print $field; }' $SOAfile
```

This is flexible enough to handle any line splitting you might have, as it counts to `field` along multiple lines.  It also adjusts the field number based on whether your zone segment contains the optional "IN" keyword.

A pure-sed solution would, instead of counting fields, use the first string of digits after an open bracket after your `/^@/`, like this:

```
SOA=$(sed -n '/^@/,/^[^;]*)/H;${;x;s/.*@[^(]*([^0-9]*//;s/[^0-9].*//;p;}' $SOAfile)
```

Looks like line noise, right?  :-)  Broken out for easier reading, it looks like this:

```
/^@/,/^[^;]*)/H              # "Hold" the meaningful part of the file...
${                           # Once we reach the end...
  x                          # Copy the hold space back to the main buffer
  s/.*@[^(]*([^0-9]*//       # Remove stuff ahead of the serial
  s/[^0-9].*//               # Remove stuff after the serial
  p                          # And print.
}
```

The idea here is that starting from the first line that begins with `@`, we copy the file into sed's hold space, then at the end of the file, do some substitutions to strip out all the text up to the serial number, and then after the serial number, and print whatever remains.

All of these work on single line and multi line zone SOA records I've tested with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following - it's your original `sed` program preceded by commands to first read *all* input lines, if applicable:

```
 SOA=$(sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}' -e 's/.*@.*SOA[^0-9]*//;s/[^0-9].*//' \
   "$SOAfile")
```

This form will work with both single- and multi-line input files.

Multi-line input files are first read as a whole before applying the substitutions.

Note: The awkward separate `-e` options are needed to keep FreeBSD happy with respect to labels and branching commands, which need a literal `\n` for termination - using separate `-e` options is a more readable alternative to splicing in literal newlines with `$'\n'`.

---

Alternative solution, using `awk`:

```
SOA=$(awk -v RS='@' '$1 == "IN" && $2 == "SOA" { print $6 }' "$SOAfile")
```

Again, this will work with both single- and multi-line record definitions.

The only constraint is that comments must not precede the serial number.

Additionally, if a file contained multiple *records*, the above would collect ALL serial numbers, separated by a newline each.

Answer (score 0):

Why `sed`? `grep` is simplest in this case:

```
grep -A1 -e '@.*SOA' 1 | grep -oe '[0-9]*'
```

or: (maybe better):

```
grep -A1 -e '@.*SOA' 1 | grep 'Serial number' | grep -oe '[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If I could rely on the serial number being on the next line (`-A1`) that would be great, but what if the file is double spaced?  Or has other commented lines within the bracketed section?  Or doesn't have comments like "Serial number"?  I'm hoping for something that will match whatever zone file that BIND will understand, not just what I expect to be the convention.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/@ IN SOA/{/[0-9]/!N;s/[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*/\1/p}' file
```

For lines that contain `@ IN SOA` if the line contains no numbers append the next line. Then extract the first sequence of numbers from the line(s).